# Notice: Undefined variable:

Tags: php, mysqli

I keep getting an error message

> "Notice: Undefined variable: pos in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project1/rate.php on line 8".

I was getting this error on line 5 but i had included the asset function, i am stuck and do not know how to fix this error. I will post the code below, please help.

Thanks in advance

**Rate.php page**

```
<?php  

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","root", "rating") or die           ("Couldnt connect to the database!"); 

 if (isset($_POST['pos']))
 $post_rating = $_POST['rating']; 

 $find_data = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM rates WHERE pos='$pos'"); 
 while($row = $mysqli->fetch_assoc($find_data)) 

   { 
  $id = $row['id']; 
  $current_rating = $row['rating']; 
  $current_hits = $row['hits'];  

   } 

   $new_hits = $current_hits + 1; 
   $update_hits = $mysqli->query("UPDATE rates SET hits = '$new_hits'     WHERE id='$id'"); 

   $pre_rating = $current_rating + $post_rating; 
   $new_rating = $pre_rating / $new_hits; 

   $update_rating = $mysqli->query("UPDATE rates SET rating = '$new_rating' WHERE id='$id'"); 

       ?>

**FGLRANK.php page**

<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en">

<head> 
<title>Football's Greatest Legends Ranking</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="style1.css" type="text/css" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body class="body">

<header class="mainheader">

  <center>
  <img src="ball.jpg" width="400" height="150" alt="Ron"align="">
  </center>
  <center>
     <font color="white" "arial" size= "6"> <b> Greatest Footballing            Legends  - You Decide!! </b> </font>
      </center>

          <nav><ul>
            <li> <a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
            <li> <a href="fgl.html">Football Legends</a></li>
            <li><a href="fglrank.php">Football Legends Ranking</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li> 

       </ul></nav>  

    </header>

    <div class="mainContent">
        <div class="content">
            <article class="topcontent">
                <header>
                    <h2> <center> <font color="black" "arial" size= "3"> <b> <i>  Legends Ranking! </i> </b> </font> </center> </h2>
                </header>

                <center>
                <content>

                 <?php

                 $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","root", "rating") or die ("Couldnt connect to the database!"); 
                 $find_data = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM rates"); 


                 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($find_data))   
                  {
                    $id = $row['id'];
                    $nameofplayer = $row['nameofplayer'];
                    $pos = $row['pos'];
                    $current_rating = $row['rating'];
                    $hits = $row['hits'];

                      echo "

                             <form action='rate.php' method='POST'>
                                 $nameofplayer: <select name='rating'>  
                                            <option>1</option>
                                            <option>2</option>
                                            <option>3</option>
                                            <option>4</option>
                                            <option>5</option>
                                            <option>6</option>
                                            <option>7</option>
                                            <option>8</option>
                                            <option>9</option>
                                            <option>10</option>
                                  </select>
                                  <input type='hidden' value='$nameofplayer' name='nameofplayer'>
                                  <input type='submit' value='Rate!'> Current Rating: "; echo $current_rating; echo " 
                                  </form>           
                      ";
                   }

                  ?>






                </content>
                </center>

                <footer>
                <p class="post-info">Greatest Legends of the game</p>                   
                </footer>

               </article>   

            <article class="bottomcontent">
                  <header>
                     <h2><a href="#" title="Second post">Second post</a></h2>
                </header>


                 <footer>
                  <p class="post-info">This post is written by Naz</p>                  
                 </footer>

                 <content>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. </p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
                    Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                    Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
                    Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </p>
              </article>    

          </div>
       </div>

      <aside class="top-sidebar">
        <article> 
             <h2>Top sidebar</h2>
             <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing    elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.   </p>
          </article>
         </aside>

            <aside class="middle-sidebar">
         <article> 
              <h2>Middle sidebar</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
          </article>
        </aside>

          <aside class="bottom-sidebar">
          <article> 
               <h2>Bottom sidebar</h2>
               <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
          </article>
      </aside>

          <footer class="mainFooter">
            <p>Copyright &copy; 2013<a href="#"    title="1stwebdesigner">1stwebdesigner.com</a></p>
      </footer>
    </body>

       </html>
```

Comment: I see too many questions like this. Take the time to learn how to [interpret errors and fix your code](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2013/05/fixing-php-errors/).

Comment: `$post_rating` - *ahem*

Answer (score 0):

```
// line 8
$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM rates WHERE pos='$pos'");
```

However, you did not set `$pos`, hence the *notice*.

I assume you meant to use `$_POST['pos']`.

Also, please take the time to read about [SQL Injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and update your code accordingly.